# Polars localized strftime equivalent from Pandas

Tags: pandas, python-polars

With Pandas, I can get localized string from date with `pandas.Series.dt.strftime`, e. g.:

```py
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "uk_UA.UTF-8")

date_ = pd.Series([datetime(2023, 11, 8, 19, 15, 7)])
date_.dt.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y")  # Wednesday, 08 November 2023 in Ukrainian

# 0    середа, 08 листопада 2023
# dtype: object
```

But how do I implement this with Polars? Polars code returns non-localized string (despite locale was set):

```
date_1 = pl.Series("", [datetime(2023, 11, 8, 19, 15, 7)])
date_1.dt.strftime(format="%A, %d %B %Y")[0]
# 'Wednesday, 08 November 2023'
```

Comment: I am going to guess that this is not possible without converting to a Python `datetime` first — Polars seems not to have any locale support.

Comment: Polars uses [chrono](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono) internally. It does support this under the `unstable-locales` feature which Polars does not enable. There doesn't seem to be any mention of the topic on https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/ - perhaps it's something that could be opened as feature request.

Comment: @jcurious thank you, created one https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/12341

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[While waiting for polars to implement locales in rust](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/12341), you can take advantage of `pyarrow.compute`'s [`strftime`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.compute.strftime.html) since going from polars to arrow is free and it does (at least seems to) observe locale.

That would look like this

```
import pyarrow.compute as pc
pl.from_arrow(pc.strftime(date_.to_arrow(), format="%A, %d %B %Y"))
### I don't have Ukraine locale installed so I can't actually test this
## other than it works with the default locale
```

You can put that in a function and either [register it with its own namespace](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.api.register_series_namespace.html) or just monkey patch it (you can do the latter in one step with lambda assignment)

```
pl.Series.pcstrftime = lambda date_, format_='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S': (
    pl.from_arrow(pc.strftime(date_.to_arrow(), format=format_))
    )
```

You can do similarly with Expressions although it's a tad more convoluted looking.

```
pl.Expr.pcstrftime =lambda date_, format_='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S': (
    date_.map_batches(lambda x, format=format_: (
        pl.Series(pc.strftime(x.to_arrow(), format=format_))
    ))
)
### which then allows you to do
pl.select(date_=date_).select(pl.col('date_').pcstrftime("%A, %d %B %Y"))
```